# fortran if condition does not work with logical from module

Tags: gcc, fortran

I work under a fortran program and have faced with a strange behaviour of "if" statement.

I have a module in the same file as the main program:

```
module platform
    character (*) SLASH, NULLDEV, COPY_CMD, MKDIR_CMD
    parameter (SLASH="\", COPY_CMD="cp -r ", NULLDEV="nul", MKDIR_CMD="mkdir")    
    !parameter (SLASH="/", COPY_CMD="cp ", NULLDEV="/dev/null", MKDIR_CMD="mkdir -p")

    logical        binary
    parameter ( binary = .TRUE. )
    !parameter ( binary = .FALSE. )
end module platform
```

And in the main program code below is the conditional statement:

```
     ...

     use module platform

     ...

     if ( .NOT. binary ) 
      call system(MKDIR_CMD // ' ' // outdir //' 2>' // NULLDEV)     
    endif
```

The "binary" parameter is false. I checked it in debugger just in case. But program does not run the call!

But, if I modify the statement with adding an any operator above "call", for example:

```
if ( .NOT. binary ) then
      a = 1
      call system(MKDIR_CMD // ' ' // outdir //' 2>' // NULLDEV)      
endif
```

All works!

UPD:
the 'outdir' is defined as:

```
character*255 ssadir, evname, outdir, evlst 
...
call getarg(2, evname)    
call getarg(3, outdir)

outdir = trim(outdir) // SLASH // trim(evname)
```

Comment: i assume the missing `then` is a typo here. have you `implicit none` in every unit?

Comment: Much more code will be necessary. Produce a minimal working compilable example which exhibits the problem. Quite possibly you will find the error yourself in the process. Be sure to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's difficult to provide an compilable example. The program woks with specific text and binary files format and for binary uses self-writed cpp class.